# Determining derived classes through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection

I want to process the Methods of classes derived from class A. Class A and the derived classes reside in different assemblies. I use reflection to get all System.Type's from the derived assembly and iterate through their methods.

```
Assembly A: class Template {...}
Assembly B: class X: A.Template {...}
Assembly B: class Y: A.Template {...}
Assembly B: class Z: A.Template {...}
```

When I try to iterate the methods of class `X` in assembly `B`, it includes all methods of class `A`. What I want to achieve is to iterate through only those methods that exist in derived classes.

I don't think that being in different assemblies matters at all but even when I try to filter the method's declaring type based on the assembly, it does not work.

I have tried using various properties of the `MethodInfo` object but have not been able to filter this out. I am sure I'm missing some silly check but have been struggling with this for long enough.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: does `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` help any?

Comment: Have you tried getting the methods by using the `DeclaredOnly` binding flag? `typeof(X).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)`

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for private methods, fields and properties and did not realize you have to use `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` flags. That, in addition to BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to get all derived types in an assembly:

```
Assembly b = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\B.dll");
var derivedTypes = b.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Template).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

And this to find any methods defined on that type:

```
Type derived = ...
var methods = derived.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                 BindingFlags.Public | 
                                 BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Or this:

```
var methods = derived.GetMethods().Where(m => m.DeclaringType == derived);
```

However, if you want to find methods defined on any subclass of `Template` (e.g. a subclass of `X`), use this:

```
Type templateType = typeof(Template);
Type derived = ...
var methods = derived.GetMethods()
                     .Where(m => templateType.IsAssignableFrom(m.DeclaringType) &&
                                 templateType != m.DeclaringType);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for private methods, fields and properties and did not realize you have to use BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic flags. That, in addition to BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly worked